# The height and width can't be adjusted when I change the size

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *


win = Tk()
win.title('McDonald ordering system')
win.geometry('600x300')


lbtitle = Label(win,text='Welcome to McDonald',bg='yellow')
lbtitle.grid(row=0,column=1,columnspan=3)

f1 = Frame(win,bd=2,width=200,height=250,relief=GROOVE)
f1.grid(row=1,column=0,rowspan=3)

f2 = Frame(win,bd=2,width=200,height=250,relief=GROOVE)
f2.grid(row=1,column=1,rowspan=3)

f3 = Frame(win,bd=2,width=200,height=250,relief=GROOVE)
f3.grid(row=1,column=2,rowspan=3)

lb1 = Label(f1,text='Big Mac')
lb1.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)

am1 = IntVar()
en1 = Entry(f1,textvariable=am1,width=5)
en1.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)

lb2 = Label(f1,text='Cheeseburger')
lb2.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)

am2 = IntVar()
en2 = Entry(f1,textvariable=am2,width=5)
en2.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)

lb3 = Label(f1,text='Nuggets')
lb3.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)

am3 = IntVar()
en3 = Entry(f1,textvariable=am3,width=5)
en3.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)

lb4 = Label(f1,text='Chicken')
lb4.grid(row=3,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)

am4 = IntVar()
en4 = Entry(f1,textvariable=am4,width=5)
en4.grid(row=3,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)


lb5 = Label(f2,text='Cheesecake')
lb5.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)

am5 = IntVar()
en5 = Entry(f2,textvariable=am5,width=5)
en5.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)

lb6 = Label(f2,text='Chocolate Cake')
lb6.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)

am6 = IntVar()
en6 = Entry(f2,textvariable=am6,width=5)
en6.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)

lb7 = Label(f2,text='McFlurry')
lb7.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)

am7 = IntVar()
en7 = Entry(f2,textvariable=am7,width=5)
en7.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)

lb8 = Label(f2,text='Pepsi')
lb8.grid(row=3,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)

am8 = IntVar()
em8 = Entry(f2,textvariable=am8,width=5)
em8.grid(row=3,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)


win.mainloop()
```

The frame works now but however if I change the height and width of the frames and I run each time the size is still the same. I do not know what's wrong but I already searched through the books mentioned that size can be set at the beginning. So how could I make the height and width adjustable? Is the size of frames count with the elements inside or I can set the sizes at the beginning?

Comment: the frame automatically size to the widget it contains. In your case there is nothing in there, so the frame get a width of 0 and a height of 0. The frame is the, you just cant see it. I wrote a few minutes an answer for it. check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63189654/trouble-using-tkinter-grid

Comment: but when I set the width and height the frame still does not appear although I added some elements inside the elements are not inside the frame

Comment: I cant see any widget that are assigned to your frames. please make a full exampel of whats wrong

Comment: @DominicSham you have to disable shrinking of the frames to the size of their childen with `grid_propagate`. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Nowhere in the code you presented do you try to set or change the height of anything.

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote in your question you imported `Frame` through `from tkinter import *`. So you don't need to import it again.

To make the window visible add `win.mainloop()` at the end of your script.

## Update:

This is how your program looks like on my system when executing it from the terminal (and having `win.mainloop()` at the end of the script).

[image]

## Update 2:

I've changed this section by removing `columnspan` from the label and disabling resizing of the frame with `grid_propagate`:

```
lbtitle = Label(win,text='Welcome to McDonald',bg='yellow')
lbtitle.grid(row=0,column=1)

f1 = Frame(win,bd=2,width=200,height=250,relief=GROOVE)
f1.grid(row=1,column=0,rowspan=3)
f1.grid_propagate(0)

f2 = Frame(win,bd=2,width=200,height=250,relief=GROOVE)
f2.grid(row=1,column=1,rowspan=3)
f2.grid_propagate(0)

f3 = Frame(win,bd=2,width=200,height=250,relief=GROOVE)
f3.grid(row=1,column=2,rowspan=3)
f3.grid_propagate(0)
```

The results looks like this:

[image]

Comment: This do not answer the question. Also it isnt requierd to explicit call the mainloop. Its just the pythonic way to do it. Cause explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: @Atlas435 It may be not necessary when you run the script in IDLE or some IDE that are made by using tkinter as well, but it is definitely necessary when you run the script in a terminal or console.

Comment: No difference after I added win.mainloop()

Comment: @DominicSham Where did you add the line? It has to be after you added all the widgets because the function is not left until the window is claused.

Comment: @acw1668 thank for letting me know, I wasnt aware of it. But in this case it does not seem helpfull for me.

Comment: @Atlas435: I tested it with the code in the question and after adding the line the window/frame appeared. What would you consider helpful then?

Comment: @Stefan Scheller which line do you mean?

Comment: @DominicSham This one: `win.mainloop()`

Comment: @DominicSham Yes. For me this solved the problem. Can you edit/update your question with the new code version?

Comment: @StefanScheller if I run this code without win.mainloop() and give a frame the bg='red' a small red line is on my window. If I explicit call mainloop the same thing happens. It just dosent fixed the problem. So it isnt an answer. If you solve it I will remove my downvote and give it a upvote.

Comment: @Atlas435 Thanks for explaining. On what system are you running the code? I am running this in the terminal on Linux and as stated above, adding the line solved it for me.

Comment: I need to apologize then. A hint: f3 is empty.. Maybe we need to ask him what he thinks a frame looks like.

Comment: @DominicSham: You should not post the updates as answers but rather edit your original question.

Comment: @Atlas435 You are right, there was quite some  misunderstanding. I thought he was asking why the window does not appear but it seems he was asking why the frames don't show a relief/groove.

Comment: Now it works after I add f1.grid_propagate(0) and thanks very much

Comment: @DominicSham Please consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it solved your problem.